# Redirect upon Facebook share?

Tags: facebook

Is there a way to redirect or launch a javascript as the user shared my website on Facebook? I only know about edge.create for Facebook Like but I want it for Facebook Share. I am a beginner so help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Yes there is if you mean he clicked button or link on your site and the share dialog popped up. And you don't need publish_stream for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, none of ways of Facebook Sharing have this ability.

You may implement it on your side if you require permission `pubish_stream` and publishing content by application.

Answer (score 0):

*Yes, it's very easy to redirect upon Facebook share.*  But please make sure to be using the [Facebook Share Dialog API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/share-dialog/), which requires registration (free) and supply AppId in API requests, and make sure *not* to be using the [Facebook Sharer API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/share-button/), which does not allow this.

How do you redirect at Facebook after sharing?

**Use the `redirect_uri` parameter.**

To quote directly from the above-linked documentation...

> **Parameter:** redirect_uri
>
> **Description:** The URL to redirect to after a person clicks a button on the dialog. Required when using URL redirection.